# SpringBoot unit test configuration

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

I created a spring-boot 1.4.0 application and I would like to internationlize it using yaml file.

I created a class for loading the configuration from the yaml file like it is explained in the documentation here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties.

I would like to create a test to check that my class has correctly loaded the properties from the yaml file.

If we keep the exemple from the documentation how to create a unit test that will load a yaml file (with a different name that application.yml) and check that the method `getUsername()` will return the value from the yaml file ?

---

Here is the code I have but still can't load the username :

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:mylocalizedprops.yml", prefix="connection")
public class ConnectionProperties {

    private String username;

    // ... getters and setters

}
```

and the test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class InternationalizationTest {
    @Autowired
    private ConnectionProperties connectionProperties;

    public void propsShouldBeNotNull() {
        assertNotNull(connectionProperties);
    }

    public void userNameShouldBeCorrect() {
        assertEquals(connectionProperties.getUsername(), expectedUserName);
    }
}
```

I have failed the userNameShouldBeCorrect test.  The file mylocalizedprops.yml is located in the src/main/resources folder of a Maven structured application.

Comment: Is the file in `/src/test/resources` or `src/main/resources`? If it is in `src/main/resources`, you will need to either put it in the test resources, or load the main source set as part of your test source sets.

Comment: It is in src/main/resources but I think it is best to create one in src/test/resources for test purpose, how could I do it ?

Comment: Copy and paste the file. The downside is you will now have to duplicate everything.

Comment: And if I want to keep using the file in src/main/resources (it is actually the case, but not working) how to proceed ?

Comment: Assuming you are using gradle, you want to add the `/src/main/resources` to your "test" source set. Add something like the following to your `build.gradle`: `sourceSets {  test { resources [${project.projectDir}/src/${sourceSet.name}/resources], [${project.projectDir}/src/main/resources] } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider this an integration test, not a unit-test because you are testing the interaction between various components. Regardless, here is how I would do it.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = YourApplication.class)
public class InternationalizationTests() {

  @Autowired
  ConnectionProperties connectionProperties;

  @Test
  public void testCorrectTranslationLoaded() {
    Assert.assertEquals("english-username", connectionProperties.getUsername());
  }    

}
```

You can also create a test configuration if you would like to, which you can specify which translation to load. You would then need different classes to test different configurations. See the docs: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: I updated my post with code, I can't load the file properly.

Answer (score 0):

Unit test can be done easily with Jmockit

```
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

    import mockit.Mock;
    import mockit.MockUp;
    import mockit.Mocked;
    import mockit.Verifications;

    class RuleApiApplicationTest {
        
        @Mocked
        private ConfigurableApplicationContext mockedContext;

        @Test
        void testApplicationRun() {
            new MockUp<SpringApplication>() {
                @Mock
                public ConfigurableApplicationContext run(Class<?> primarySource, String... args) {
                    return mockedContext;
                }
            };

            RuleApiApplication.main(new String[]{});
            
            new Verifications() {{
                SpringApplication.run(RuleApiApplication.class, new String[]{});
            }};
        }
    }
```